# How to write a proper Junit test for this Rest client controller

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I know that this is very bold question, but maybe someone can at least lead on the correct way....

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model) {  
        model.addAttribute("logedUser", logedUser);
        final String uri = new String(URL + "list");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();     
        HttpEntity entity = getHeader();
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);         
        String temp = response.getBody();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {       
            User[] obj = mapper.readValue(temp, User[].class);
            List<User> userList= Arrays.asList(obj);
            model.addAttribute("users", userList);
            //String temps = logedUser.getUserType().toString();
            System.out.println(logedUser.getUserType().toString());

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
        return "users";
    }
```

Test:
@Test

```
public void btestList() throws Exception{

    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.add(new User());
    users.add(new User());
    UserController mock = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(UserController.class);
    Mockito.when(mock.listUsers(model)).thenReturn((String) "users");

    mockMvc.perform(get("/users"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(view().name("users"));

}
```

So, tried to write a test for this controller and got this:
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)

What I'm doing wrong here ?
P.s controller works just fine.

Comment: You can use MockMVC - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html

Example - http://blog.zenika.com/2013/01/15/spring-mvc-test-framework/

Comment: Thanks for advice, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

With `Mockito.when(mock.listUsers(model)).thenReturn((String) "users");` you are essentially mocking the very method you are trying to test.

Also, when using @RestController, the return value are not views, so I'm not sure `view().name("users")` is correct. Perhaps it may work, but the point is that a RestController isn't meant to return views. Also, your code doesn't show how you create your mockMvc, so I'm unsure how it is wired.

**The following test code would work:**

```
public class UserControllerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void btestList() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/users"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("users"));
    }
}
```

A simplified version of your controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        return "users";
    }
}
```